# Jquery Query Builder - operator IN with Integer and value_separator

Tags: jquery-query-builder

I'm unable to provide multiple values for **IN Operator** which is of type **Integer**.

Below is the reference JSFiddle, where I unable pass multiple values for IN Operator.

https://jsfiddle.net/z7dem1mg/2/

Piece of code:
`{
    id: 'count',
    label: 'Count',
    type: 'integer',
    input: 'text',
    value_separator: ','
}`

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://querybuilder.js.org/index.html#filters

Comment: "value_separator (string): Used the split and join the value when a text input is used with an operator allowing multiple values (between for example)."
http://querybuilder.js.org/index.html#filters

So, I think at the moment, thats not the way it works.

There is already a git-Issues:
https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/451